# What is the meaning of "Set parameter TokenServer to value SANTOS-SURFACE-" in Gurobi?

Tags: python, gurobi

When I reading gurobi example in "Model Building in Mathematical Programming",which the example is "Food Manufacture I". In this example, after create a model and the variable it said:

"Using license file c:\gurobi\gurobi.lic
Set parameter TokenServer to value SANTOS-SURFACE-"

In this case, the establishment of the model and the setting of variables are as follows:

```py
import gurobipy as gp
from gurobipy import GRB
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
#tested with Python 3.7 & Gurobi 9
 
months = ["Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun"]
oils = ["VEG1", "VEG2", "OIL1", "OIL2", "OIL3"]
 
food = gp.Model('Food Manufacture I')
# Quantity of food produced in each period
produce = food.addVars(months, name="Produce")
# Quantity bought of each product in each period
buy = food.addVars(months, oils, name = "Buy")
# Quantity used of each product  in each period
consume = food.addVars(months, oils, name = "Use")
# Quantity stored of each product  in each period
store = food.addVars(months, oils, name = "Store")
```

Please tell me the purpose of this content, and what is the meaning of "SANTOS-SURFACE", how does this affect the establishment of variables.
And in this case, why can the setting of model parameters be directly passed into a list? In gurobi, model.addVar(),the first parameter passed in should be the lb parameter, which is the lower bound. This list is clearly not the lower bound.

I have try search this concent in bing, browsed the TokenServer program on the official website of Gurobi, didn't solve my problem.
I want to know does this operation have an impact on the establishment of variables?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.